# Empty proof as standalone

Tags: amsthm, standalone, proof-package

I've made an empty proof as a joke (the worst kind of visual proof). It works fine when I use the `article` document class,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: Proof - qed]

but I want to get rid of page numbers and other article-like behavior.
When I try to compile it as a `standalone` using

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

in the preamble, it gives me the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

How can I make an empty proof as a `standalone` document, preferably using the `proof` environment from `amsthm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `preview`-option.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

This will give you the following result:

[image]

Comment: Why is needed the package `standalone`? Your MWE works without it too :-)

Comment: @Zarko You're right, I just copied it from OP. I will edit.

Comment: @Zarko thank you for pointing this out. I will remove it from my question.

Comment: I also would  add in preamble `\usepackage{lipsum}` and than wrote `\begin{proof}
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}` and show the result in answer. With this OP will get better filling about obtained result.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your suggestion, I added it.

Answer (score 8):

Embedding the `proof` inside a `minipage` works:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]